# PHP Fatal error: Could not queue new timer in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I write a simple web application for my compnay that can let user log in to arrange their work time.  Besides, user can also view the report of he's or she's attandence that I use ajax to callback from java.jar. (We use java to analyze)I use Xampp to set up the server in virtual machine HyperV and it can run successfully at the begining but after twenty hours or more than one day it won't let anyone to log in.

I open the error.log shows that :

> PHP Fatal error: Could not queue new timer in Unknown on line 0

. . . and than:

> PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Unknown Error

I don't understand what can cause that happend and how to solve it.
I alreday know is when I restarted the apache server, it can still be used till that error happened.

My System Enviroment :
win7 64 bit HyperV
xampp Apache/2.4.18, php/7.0.6, mysql/ 5.1

Here is my code:

mysql_start.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:html;charset=utf-8");

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "cc1234";
$dbname     = "cc_tw000427";

$conn = null;

try {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error_message = "Connect Error (" .$conn->connect_errno ." )" . $conn->connect_error;
    error_log($error_message, 3, "php_error_log");
    header("location:login.php?err=$e");
}

$conn->set_charset("utf-8");
$strDBColLoingAccount = "AccountID";
```

checklogin.php

```
session_start();
include_once("mysql_start.php");

$yid   = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "yid"));
$passd = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"passd"));

$strSql = "SELECT acc.*, b.String_10_1 FROM basicstoreinfomanageacc_sub acc,basicstoreinfo b
           WHERE acc.$strDBColLoingAccount ='$yid' AND acc.String_50_1 = b.String_50_1";
$result = $conn->query($strSql);
$n      = $result->num_rows;
if ($n == 0) {
  header("Location:../desktop/login.php?err=1");
  echo "Error 1";
    exit();
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $passd_right = $row["AccountPwd"];
    $user_id     = $row["AccountID"];
    $user_name   = $row["AccountName"];
    $user_dep_id = $row["String_10_1"];
    $user_dep    = $row['String_50_1'];
}
$result->close();

if (($passd_right == "") || ($passd_right == NULL)){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id']   = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    header("location:newpwd.php");
    exit();
}

if ($passd == $passd_right) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    $_SESSION['loginOK'] = 'yes';
    $_SESSION['year_i']  = date('Y',time());
    $_SESSION['year_f']  = date('Y',time());
    $_SESSION['month_i'] = date('m',time());
    $_SESSION['month_f'] = date('m',time());
    $_SESSION['day_i']   = date('d',time());
    $_SESSION['day_f']   = date('d',time());
    $_SESSION['Hour']    = date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime('+6 hour'));
    $_SESSION['user_dep_id'] = $user_dep_id;
    $_SESSION['user_dep'] = $user_dep;
    header("Location:../desktop/Punch.php");
} else {
        header("Location:../desktop/login.php?err=1");
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Next two *.php files are used to receive the post from the web.
The select.php is used to select the data from mysql than output in html tag.
The save.php is used to save the data post from web.

select.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../control/mysql_start.php';
$strYear     = $_POST['year'];
$strMonth    = $_POST['month'];
$strDay      = $_POST['day'];
        .
        .//some codes
        .
$strSql = "SELECT * FROM basicemploymentinfo bei WHERE bei.BelongStore = '". $_SESSION['user_dep']."'".
          "AND ((bei.datetime_2 is null AND bei.datetime_3 is null) OR (bei.datetime_2 is null AND bei.datetime_3 >= STR_TO_DATE('" . $strDate . "', '%Y-%m-%d'))" .
          " OR (bei.datetime_2 <= STR_TO_DATE('" . $strDate . "', '%Y-%m-%d') AND bei.datetime_3 is null)" .
          " OR (bei.datetime_2 <= STR_TO_DATE('" . $strDate . "', '%Y-%m-%d') AND bei.datetime_3 >= STR_TO_DATE('" . $strDate . "', '%Y-%m-%d'))) "
          ."AND bei.Active ='Y'";

$EmpId   = array();
$EmpName = array();

if ($result = $conn->query($strSql)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($EmpId, $row['String_20_1']);
        array_push($EmpName, $row['String_20_2']);
        .
        .//some codes
        .
    }
}
$Emp = array_combine($EmpId, $EmpName);

$strSql = " SELECT Distinct date_format(DateTime_1, '%e') as date, AutoCheck
            FROM hrotcheck
            WHERE date_format(DateTime_1, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$newformat'
            AND AutoCheck = 'C'
            AND String_20_1 IN ($array_emp_id)";

if ($result = $conn->query($strSql)) {
    $n = $result->num_rows;
    if ($n > 0) { $checkboxVerify = 'C';}
}
$result->close();

foreach ($Emp as $EId => $EName)
{
        .
        .//some codes
        .
        $strSql = "SELECT RegularM_1, RegularM_2, FORMAT(OT_3, 1) as OT_3, TOM, TOTM, Notes, AutoCheck FROM hrotcheck where string_20_1 = '" . $EId . "' AND"." date_format(DateTime_1,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$newformat'";
        $result = $conn->query($strSql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                $RegularM_1 = $row['RegularM_1'];
                $RegularM_2 = $row['RegularM_2'];
                $OT3   = $row['OT_3'];
                $tom   = $row['TOM'];
                $totm  = $row['TOTM'];
                $notes = $row['Notes'];
            }
        }
        $result->close();
        .
        .//I did a lot of SQL select and use that to create htmltable
        .
        $output .= '
                    <tr data-table="sub">
                        <td>'.$row['string_20_1'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['string_20_2'].'</td>
                            .
                            .//<td>...</td>
                            .
                        <td class="'.$condition16.'">'.$notes.'</td>
                        <td class="'.$condition17.'"></td>
                    </tr>
                ';
}
        .
        .//some codes
        .
$strSql01 = "SELECT * FROM manufacturejobschedulingpersonal where string_20_1 = '".
          $row['string_20_1']."' AND"." date_format(DateTime_1,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$newformat'";
$result01 = $conn->query($strSql01);

if ($result01->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row01 = $result01->fetch_assoc()) {
        .
        .//some codes
        .
    }
}
$result01->close();
        .
        .//some codes
        .
$result->close();
$conn->close();

echo $optionUse.'?'.$checkboxVerify.'?'.$output.'?'.$hasCheckDate;
?>
```

save.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../control/mysql_start.php';

$arrayObjs = $_POST;
        .
        .//some codes
        .
$msDanger = '';

foreach($arrayObjs as $array)
{
    foreach($array as $row)
    {
        $UserId          = $row['UserId'];
        $UserName        = $row['UserName'];
        .
        .//some codes
        .
        $strSql = "SELECT * FROM manufacturejobschedulingpersonal where string_20_1 = '".
                  $UserId."' AND"." date_format(DateTime_1,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$DateTime_1'";
        $result = $conn->query($strSql);

        if( $result->num_rows > 0) {
            if ($table == 'main') {
                $strSql = "Update manufacturejobschedulingpersonal SET String_10_1 ='$String_10_1', String_Assist01 ='$assist_1',String_Assist02='$assist_2' where string_20_1 = '".
                          $UserId."' AND"." date_format(DateTime_1,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$DateTime_1'";
            } else {
                $strSql = "Update manufacturejobschedulingpersonal SET String_10_1 ='$String_10_1' where string_20_1 = '".
                          $UserId."' AND"." date_format(DateTime_1,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$DateTime_1'";
            }
            $result = $conn->query($strSql);
        } else {
            $strSql = "INSERT INTO manufacturejobschedulingpersonal (string_20_1,string_20_2,YM,DateTime_1,String_10_1,String_Assist01,String_Assist02)".
                      "VALUES ( '$UserId', '$UserName', '$YM', '$DateTime_1', '$String_10_1','$assist_1','$assist_2')";
            $result = $conn->query($strSql);
        }
        .
        .//A lot of sql CRUD
        .
    }
}
$conn->close();
$last_line = exec('java -jar C:/CCERP/ChainCodeERP/ExtraModule/HRMultiOTCheck/HRMultiOTCheck.jar -ssa '.$javaDate.' ' .$javaDepId, $return_var);
echo 'Updated';
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your database connection already?

Comment: Yes, I checked.
`$servername = "127.0.0.1";//before I used "localhost"
$username   = "xxx";
$password   = "xxx";
$dbname     = "xxx";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $error_message = "Connection Error : (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") ". $conn->connect_error;
    error_log($error_message, 3, "php_error_log");
    header("location:login.php?err=$error_message");
}`

Comment: The beginning error is  `(HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 'MySQL' `, So, I change the localhost to 127.0.0.1. But, this is the same like that. It started just okay, then after few hours it dead.

Comment: I don't believe,  that you really used xxx as username and password,  but I would check that first. On local database I always saw the username "root" and no password ("").

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is what I used now : 
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username   = "root"; 
$password   = "cc1234" ; 
$dbname     = "cc_tw000427";

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your full code, because that would help me help you.

Comment: Thank you, Igor. I have edited my post and deleted some similar codes.