# PHP Fatal error: Could not delete queued timer in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysqli, ini, wine

I'm getting the error when trying to access any page running on the builtin php webserver (including just a phpinfo):

```
Fatal error: Could not delete queued timer in Unknown on line 0
```

This is the command I am using to run the server

```
~/php-win$ wine php.exe -S localhost:8080
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/92L2WaQg) is the content of my php.ini file, which I am assuming is the cause of the error because of the [Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211677/13457642) part.

Through trial and error I have discovered that if I comment out the `max_input_time` value then pages will load fine however the error shows up at the bottom of the page instead. See the below image:[image]

I also had the exact same issue when attempting to set up an EasyPHP server as well (through wine also).

The only other question I could find on this error was [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200382/php-fatal-error-could-not-queue-new-timer-in-unknown-on-line-0) however this is happening when I run any file through the built-in webserver, including a blank file.

Also, I am using PHP 7.1.3

Comment: Any specific reason to use wine here?

Comment: @Viney I don't have root access on the machine I'm using, and can't find any PHP binaries for Debian, so wine seems to work well. If you have any solutions for getting PHP binaries on debian (with MySQL support), I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: Fair enough, try this I've posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your php.ini and put the location of extension folder , the folder named `ext` inside your php folder

php.ini

```
    ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
    ; http://php.net/extension-dir
    ; extension_dir = "./"
    ; On windows:
     extension_dir = "/media/viney/01D58852BCA3B9C0/UwAmp/bin/php/php-7.0.3/ext"
```

Then I  enable a few extensions in php.ini

php.ini

```
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

Now if I run php, extenions get loaded

```
    viney@Notebook:/media/viney/01D58852BCA3B9C0/UwAmp/bin/php/php-7.0.3$ wine php -S localhost:8080
    PHP 7.0.3 Development Server started at Mon May  4 09:28:07 2020
    Listening on http://localhost:8080
    Document root is Z:\media\viney\01D58852BCA3B9C0\UwAmp\bin\php\php-7.0.3
    Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Comment: I'm already doing this, I think because I'm using an absolute path to load the extensions. [Here](https://pastebin.com/92L2WaQg) is my php.ini. Do the quotes around the path matter?

Comment: I see but did you note `extension_dir` is a path to real filesystem (/media/viney/01D58852BCA3B9C0/ is a partition on disk)  path and not to some virtual drive (`Z:`) that wine mounts. Try move the php folder to ~  and then try from there. Regarding quotes they are necessary when you have a hyphen in your path